# Monitoring background Threads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to monitor a thread that i set running in the background. I need to be alerted when it is finished executing.

```
- (IBAction) btnGreaterTen_clicked :(id)sender{

    self.searchDistance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble : 10];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake (120.0, 185.0, 80, 80);

    activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    activity.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;


    [navigationUpdateFromDetail.window addSubview: activity];


    [activity startAnimating];


    thread = [[NSThread alloc] init];
    [thread start];

[self performSelectorInBackground: @selector (getSetDisplay) withObject:nil];         

if(thread.isFinished == YES){
    [activity stopAnimating];
}
 }
```

The above code what i have after trying different set up in order to achieve the end result. I am trying to animate the UIActivityIndicator while I use that method "getSetDisplay" to grab information from the net.

The function is good, but the Activity indicator was not coming up. I was told that i needed to run the process on a background thread and the animation on the main thread. My problem now is how do I monitor for when this process is done to stop the activity indicator. thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider the problem from a different angle: you should let your "main thread" continue to run, and let your "secondary thread" call a selector on the main thread when it is done doing work.

To accomplish this, you should use the `performSelectorOnMainThread` method, and call it from your secondary thread. Its prototype is `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait`.   You should put your "finishing" code in a method, and then do something like:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doneDoingWork) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: i tried that method, but the UIActivity from what i understand needs to run on the main thread, and the OS puts it on that thread. Thats why im running my method on the background. i just need to know how to monitor it

Comment: Consider putting something like this at the end of your `getSetDisplay` method:

`[activity performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]`

Comment: Your thread = [[NSThread alloc] init]; doesn't appear to do anything at all. You're spawning a thread there, then another one with the performSelectorInBackground call.

The above comments are probably the way I would go... Or you could use NSNotifications to message between the background op and the foreground op.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys. I finally got a solution that worked thanks to Mike and his above comment.

```
- (IBAction) btnGreaterTen_clicked :(id)sender{

self.searchDistance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble : 10];


[activity startAnimating];

NSLog(@" search value after change %@", [searchDistance description]);

[self performSelectorInBackground: @selector (getSetDisplay) withObject: nil];
}
```

I started the activity indicator on with the "[activity startAnimating]" which runs on the main thread. Then i started my method on a background thread with the "performSelectorInBackground". And at the end of my "getSetDisplay" method, i placed the following statement.

```
[activity performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector (stopAnimating) withObject:nil   waitUntilDone:NO];
```

This is just another way to say [activity stopAnimating], which is working on the main thread.

Thank you to all that responded.